# Does Azure Data Factory (ADF) support linked service Azure Cosmos DB (Table API)?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Does Azure Data Factory (ADF) support linked service Azure Cosmos DB (Table API)? If not, is it possible to create linked service Azure Table Storage and provide connection string of Cosmos DB (Table API)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support Azure Cosmos DB (Table API), only support Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API):

[image]

Please reference: [Supported data stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores)

When we create the linked Azure Table Storage, there is no way to provide the connection string of Cosmos DB (Table API).

[image]

Hope this helps.